# What is the correct approach when trying to remove some items in ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, concurrency

Is this better:

```
    public void Test()
    {

        ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();

        dictionary.TryAdd(0, "A");
        dictionary.TryAdd(1, "B");
        dictionary.TryAdd(2, "A");
        dictionary.TryAdd(3, "D");

        foreach (var item in dictionary)
        {
            string foundItem;

            if (dictionary.TryGetValue(item.Key, out foundItem))
            {
                if (foundItem == "A")
                {
                    if (dictionary.TryRemove(item.Key, out foundItem))
                    {
                        // Success
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Than this?:

```
    public void Test2()
    {

        ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();

        dictionary.TryAdd(0, "A");
        dictionary.TryAdd(1, "B");
        dictionary.TryAdd(2, "A");
        dictionary.TryAdd(3, "D");

        foreach (var item in dictionary)
        {
            string foundItem;

            if (item.Value == "A")
            {
                if (dictionary.TryRemove(item.Key, out foundItem))
                {
                    // Success
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

This method will be accessed by multiple thread.

My confusion is, whenever I want to remove an item, I try to get it first, then remove it. But in the first place, I have used `foreach` loop, meaning I have already get the item. Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: First option doesn't makes sense. When you already have an item with you, why would you call `TryGetValue` :?

Comment: I use `TryGetValue` because I'm thinking may be I may get an outdated value... :)

Comment: Well what if some thread modified the value after you called `TryGetValue` but before you call `TryRemove` ? Still there is a race :)

Comment: I thought `TryGeValue` will block other methods like `TryRemove`. Isn't like that?

Comment: It may be locking internally(or lock free). But I'm talking about what happens when some thread modifies the value after the `TryGeValue` returns, but before the `TryRemove` is called. Think about it. I'd go with second option or Jon's answer below,

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I got the point now. And I have no idea on how to handle such scenario. I'd go with Jon's answer too.

Comment: This seems like a *very* bad idea.  You can write the code so it won't crash, but what actually happens isn't going to be deterministic at all.  You can make so very few assumptions about what's actually going to happen when you run it that it's unlikely to be particularly useful, and it's highly likely to end up causing some bugs somewhere in your application.  `ConcurrentDictionary` is designed to be used such that you're only ever performing one method at a time, not many operations in aggregate.  You're probably better off just using a regular dictionary and locking around access to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any benefit in the first approach. I'd just use LINQ to find the items though:

```
foreach (var entry in dictionary.Where(e => e.Value == "A"))
{
    string ignored;
    // Do you actually need to check the return value?
    dictionary.TryRemove(entry.Key, out ignored);
}
```

Of course, you need to consider what you want to happen if another thread adds a new entry with value `"A"` or updates an existing entry (possibly to make the value `"A"`, possibly to make the value not-`"A"` while you're iterating... does it matter to you whether or not that entry is removed? It's not guaranteed what will happen. (The iterator doesn't take a snapshot, but isn't guaranteed to return entirely up-to-date data either.)

You *may* want to check that the value you've removed really is `"A"` by checking the variable I've called `ignored` afterwards. It really depends on your context. When you've got multiple threads modifying the map, you need to think that anything can happen at any time - within the operations that your code actually performs.

There's also the fact that you're effectively having to trawl through the whole dictionary... are you looking up by key elsewhere?

Comment: That's a big relief for me Jon.. I think I misunderstood the locking mechanism of this collection.

Comment: Hi Jon, if I do, `dictionary.TryGetValue(entry.Key, out ignored);` and then check if `ignored == "A"` and then perform `dictionary.TryRemove(entry.Key, out ignored);` will that ensure I am not getting an outdated value? If NO, then how can I make sure that I'm getting the latest value?

Comment: @fiberOptics: No, it won't - because something could still change the value *after* the `TryGet` but before the `TryRemove`. As per my answer, if you want to check that the entry you removed had a value of `"A"`, use the out parameter for `TryRemove`.

Comment: I think that is the only option. Thanks Jon.

Comment: @JonSkeet Of course, that begs the question of what you should actually do if you find that you removed an item with a value other than "A"?  Do you add it back in again?  What if someone else tried to add/update the value after you removed it and before you added it back, or what if someone tried to actually remove it (like, for real) after you removed it and before you add it back in?

Comment: @Servy: Indeed - that's why I said it really depends on the context of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JonSkeet I know you understand the gravity of these types of issues, but I'm getting the impression that the OP doesn't understand all of the various ways in which a solution like this is complicated by multithreaded access to the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Second approach sounds good. If you have multiple threads trying to remove the item some of them will fail in the TryRemove but one will succeed, which should be good.